# SQL-Functions with schemaRDD using language integrated SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter a schemaRDD using  language integrated SQL based on SQL functions. For example I want to run

```
SELECT name FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%AHSAN%' AND name regexp '^[A-Z]{20}$'
```

**How can I use such SQL functions in people.where()?**

**Reference:**

For language integrated SQL, I am following the example given [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#writing-language-integrated-relational-queries).

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
val people: RDD[Person] = ... // An RDD of case class objects, from the first example.
// The following is the same as 'SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 10 AND age <= 19'
val teenagers = people.where('age >= 10).where('age <= 19).select('name)
teenagers.map(t => "Name: " + t(0)).collect().foreach(println)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL functions like numeric operators. E.g.,

```
people.where('name like "%AHSAN%").where('name rlike "^[A-Z]{20}$").select('name)
```

There is no `regexp` in Spark SQL but it's same as `rlike`.

Comment: can we have two where conditions ?

Comment: Yep. Multiple where conditions are okay.