# filter DataFrame with Regex with Spark in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter out rows in Spark `DataFrame` that have Email column that look like real, here's what I tried:

```
df.filter($"Email" match {case ".*@.*".r => true case _ => false})
```

But this doesn't work. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Use `rlike` like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249685/sql-functions-with-schemardd-using-language-integrated-sql

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To expand on @TomTom101's comment, the code you're looking for is:

```
df.filter($"Email" rlike ".*@.*")
```

The primary reason why the `match` doesn't work is because `DataFrame` has two [filter functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) which take either a String or a Column. This is unlike `RDD` with one [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) that takes a function from `T` to Boolean.

Comment: Matthew, this bit of code works in the Spark REPL but not in my main file. What import do I need to run this?

Comment: @BruceWayne, the REPL configures some things for you that you need to configure yourself in an App. So two Qs: 1) Does your function work with simpler operations (you can successfully create and count a dataframe, for example)?
2) are you running the same Spark version for your REPL and wherever the main file is run?

Comment: Matthew, you're right. I needed to add `val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)` and `import sqlContext.implicits._`